# Why this code does not throw StackOverflow exception

Tags: clojure, jvm

In clojure v1.6.0, this code just runs forever and consumes 100% of one core:

```
(defn average [x y] (/ (+ x y) 2))

(defn improve [guess x]
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defn sqrt-iter [guess x]
  (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x))

(sqrt-iter 1 4)
```

I'd expect it to throw a `StackOverflowError` immediately, but it doesn't.

Any explanation why it happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because 1 is a long. The code starts computing extremely long rationals, and slows to a crawl after a few iterations. If you run it with 1.0 and 4 it blows the stack very quickly after a few thousand calls (may vary depending on your jvm parameters).

Comment: To overflow it need to perform just several thousands calls. Is it really long arithmetic *that slow* so that it cannot compute 10k divisions and sums quickly?

Comment: It's not long arithmetic. It's a Ratio, which contains BigIntegers in the denominator and numerator. BigIntegers will grow arbitrarily long. See https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ratio.java