# Clojure - optimize a threaded map reduce

Tags: optimization, clojure, reduce

I have the following code :

```
(defn series-sum
  "Compute a series : (+ 1 1/4 1/7 1/10 1/13 1/16 ...)"
  [n]
  (->> (iterate (partial + 3) 1)
       (map #(/ 1 %))
       (take n)
       (reduce +)
       float
       (format "%.2f")
       (str)))
```

It is working just fine, except that it's running time explodes when numbers get big. On my computer `(series-sum 2500)` is maybe a second or two, but `(series-sum 25000)` and I have to kill my REPL.

I tried moving `(take n)` as far as possible, but that is not enough. I feel that I don't understand something about Clojure since I don't see why it would be slower (I would expect `(series-sum 25000)` to take roughly 10 times as `(series-sum 2500)`).

There is an obvious loop/recur solution to optimize it, but I like the idea of being able to print the steps and to have one step (the `(take n)` looking like the docstring).

How can I improve the performance of this code while maintaining debuggability ?

Better yet, can I measure the time of each step to see the one taking time ?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26954404/251311

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it is relevant to @zerkms's link. You map to rationals, probably should better map to floats:

```
(defn series-sum
  "Compute a series : (+ 1 1/4 1/7 1/10 1/13 1/16 ...)"
  [n]
  (->> (iterate (partial + 3) 1)
       (take n)
       (map #(/ 1.0 %))
       (reduce +)
       (format "%.2f")))
```

now it works much faster:

```
user> (time (series-sum 2500000))
"Elapsed time: 686.233199 msecs"
"5,95"
```

Comment: Ah shame : I liked being able to print the sequence as rationals.. @cfrick that is really nice, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For this type of mathematical operation, computing in a loop is faster than using lazy sequences. This is an order of magnitude faster than the other answer for me:

```
(defn series-sum
  [n]
  (loop [i 0
         acc 0.0]
    (if (< i n)
      (recur (inc i)
             (+ acc (/ (float 1) (inc (* 3 i)))))
      (format "%.2f" acc))))
```

Note: you don't need the `str` because `format` returns a string.

Edit: of course this is not the main issue with the code in the original question. The bulk of the improvement comes from eliminating rationals as shown by the other answer. This is just a further optimization.

Comment: Obviously the loop is faster, but are you sure that's the main problem? I expected the main issue to be the increasing size of rationals causing each multiplication to take longer. Your solution is faster, but you switch to floats as well as using a loop, making it hard to know which is the main performance improvement.

Comment: Yes, I meant an order of magnitude faster than the switch-to-float answer, which was already about three orders of magnitude faster than OP's rationals for n in the low thousands.